# More... Every or Every... More

Tags: parts-of-speech

What expression is more natural for native speakers?

> I'm tired, more every day.

Or

> I'm tired, every day more.

Comment: Hello, @Cardinal, what I tried to communicate is that something increases, in this case the tiredness.

Comment: Either one works.

Comment: What about _I’m more tired every day._ That’s how I’d probably say it.

Comment: J.R.'s suggestion is the most natural one.  If you really want to phrase it the way you originally suggested, it would sound more natural to add *"than the day before"* to the end.  As it is, it sounds kind of "dangling" - we hear "every day more" and want to say "more what?"

Comment: I think "I'm tired, every day more *so*." would be OK for the second example. Otherwise you can't tell what *more* is modifying.

Comment: In this context *more every day* is and *every day more* is not idiomatic.

Everyone will understand *every day more* and equally, everyone will hear it as coming from a non-native speaker.

Comment: *More* natural wouldn't make either expression acceptable. The point is that neither is natural.

If you wanted to go into it further that would be a different Question…

Comment: I would just simply say: _I'm more tired every day_.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples sound a little unnatural. It's not 100% clear what you are trying to say. Correct me if I am wrong, but I assume you are trying to say that with each day that passes you feel more tired than the previous day. If that is your intended meaning, I would use something like the following:

> I feel more and more tired (with) every day.
>
> I'm getting more and more tired (with) every day.

or

> I feel more and more tired with every passing day.

... although admittedly that final sentence has a slightly formal feel to it.

Answer (score 0):

Neither sounds natural to me.  I might say:

I'm tired, more and more every day.   [You could say this to your doctor.]

or I might say:

Every day, I feel tireder than the day before.  [You could also say this to your doctor.  Or you might say it to a friend as a prelude to asking your friend if he or she thinks you should go to a doctor.]

Comment: Yes, Nan, you could… and how exactly would you justfity either of those not as every-day statements but according to grammatical rules?